# Get String.xml values in the ViewModel - MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have the following list in my `viewModel`. However in order to support multiple language, I want this string to come from `string.xml`. Is it possible?

```
private List<Thing> _items = new List<Thing>()
{
   new Thing("Open"),
   new Thing("Close"),
};
```

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/

Comment: That means you need to have your strings duplicated across projects (android/ios, etc). If you want to have your locales at just one place (your PCL), you can use this library: https://github.com/xleon/I18N-Portable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are building native android and iOS apps you could have the interface:

```
public interface ILocalization {
    string GetLocalizedString(string key);
}
```

And in the Android and iOS projects you have a class that implements the interface, Android:

```
public class LocalizationAndroid : ILocalization
{
    public Activity context;

    public LocalizationAndroid(Activity _context) {
        context = _context;
    }

    public string GetLocalizedString(string key)
    {
        var resourceId = (int)typeof(Resource.String).GetField(key).GetValue(null);
        return context.GetString(resourceId);
    }
}
```

iOS:

```
public class LocalizationIOS : ILocalization
{
    public string GetLocalizedString(string key)
    {
        return NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString(key, null);
    }
}
```

And then pass one instance of the class (instantiated in your view) to the view model to get the strings. The strings must be placed at the **Localizable.strings** file for the iOS project and at the **Strings.xml** file for the Android project.

On the ViewModel you would have:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ILocalization LocalizationObject;

    private List<Thing> _items;

    public MyViewModel(ILocalization _localizationObject)
    {
        LocalizationObject = _localizationObject;
        _items.Add(new Thing(LocalizationObject.GetLocalizedString("Open")));
        _items.Add(new Thing(LocalizationObject.GetLocalizedString("Closed")));
    }
}
```

This, considering the fact that you added the two strings "Open" and "Closed" for the "Open" and "Closed" keys on the **Strings.xml**(Android) and the **Localizable.strings** (iOS).

Comment: could you please also show a sample code from `ViewModel` side as well.

Comment: Are `LocalizationAndroid` and `ILocalizationAndroid` in the Android project not in the Common portable class?

Comment: LocalizationAndroid at the Android project, ILocalization at the PCL project

Comment: I am getting the following error in the viewmodel constructor :`MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to construct and initialize ViewModel for type FieldModule.Common.ViewModels.DowntimeEditorViewModel from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator - check InnerException for more information`

Comment: By the way, I put `ILocalization` in the `Utility` folder in the PCL project.

Comment: Do you explicitly instantiate the ViewModel in your view?

Comment: I am calling as follows to pass init parameters  `ShowViewModel<MyViewModel>(new { Id = _selectedItem.Id, date = Date });`

Comment: so your ViewModel doen't have a constructor that takes the LocalizationObject?

Comment: I think previous to intantiating the ViewModel, in the android project you could do: 
Mvx.RegisterSingleton<ILocalization>(new LocalizationAndroid(Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity> ().Activity));
And then, instead of having the ILocalization property inside it and needing it passed on the constructor, you could call the localizationObject as:
Mvx.Resolve<ILocalization>().GetLocalizedString("Open");

Comment: In which file should I put `Mvx.RegisterSingleton<ILocalization>(new LocalizationAndroid(Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity> ().Activity)); ` ?

Comment: In the same file as you have "ShowViewModel<MyViewModel>(new { Id = _selectedItem.Id, date = Date });", before it

Comment: It does not find/recognize `LocalizationAndroid` and `IMxAndroidCurrentTopActivity` in the previous ViewModel

Comment: do you have an App class?

Comment: it should be put in the android project, somewhere it pass before loading "MyViewModel".

Comment: What should I put in the `App.cs`? By the way, I have accepted your answer.

Comment: this: Mvx.RegisterSingleton<ILocalization>(new LocalizationAndroid(Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity> ().Activity));